# Solving colorless jigsaw puzzles by algorithms instead of combinatorics?

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, discrete-mathematics

Given a list of randomized `n` no-color puzzle pieces ([see examples](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/jigsaw-puzzle-blank-template-cutting-guidelines-ratio-60523195.jpg)) with fixed orientation, how many solutions does it exist?

- It is known that there exists at least one solution.
- The dimension of the puzzle is unknown. But the solution will always be in the shape of a full rectangle.
- The puzzle pieces can't be rotated or mirrored. The orientations are fixed.
- Since the puzzle pieces are colorless, you'd get a different solution if two identical pieces manage to swap places.

One could find the solution mathematically using combinatorics since different solutions only occur when there are identical pieces. For example, for two different pieces with three identical pieces each there are 3!*3! = 36 solutions.

However, how does one solve this by algorithm? I have tried to turn the puzzle into a graph but I have no idea what to do next, especially when there are identical pieces. I have read that BFS and DFS could help but I cannot figure out how exactly.

Thank you for any insights.

Comment: BFS (Breadth-First Search) and DFS (Depth-First Search)  are Algorithms to traverse a tree, look at [Tree Traversal Algorithms] (https://towardsdatascience.com/4-types-of-tree-traversal-algorithms-d56328450846).  you can generate the possible combination (resulting in tree) by using for example [Branch and Bound (B&B) Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) , where each time you look at the possible combination, and after that eliminate the combination that do not lead to a solution. you can treat the duplication as well.